# Function template: point of instantiation and declaration

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I have a question on code from Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed Page 749-750.  This code is trying to show point of instantiation binding.  Stroustrup says just before this code that *"Each use of a template for a given set of template arguments defines a point of instantiation.  For a function template, that point (of instantiation) is in the nearest global or namespace scope enclosing its use, just after the declaration that contains that use."*.

> ```
> void g(int);
>
> template<typename T> 
> void f(T a)
> {
>    g(a); // g is bound at a point of instantiation
> }
>
> void h(int i) 
> {
>    extern void g(double);
>    f(i); 
> }
> // point of declaration for f<int>
> ```

Questions regarding this code:

- Is the point of instantiation `f(i)`?  It is a use of a template for a given set of arguments.  If not what is it?
- Stroustrup comments that the "point of declaration" for `f<int>` is after `h() {}`.  Is the point of declaration different than point of instantiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>*All standard references below refers to [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/).*</sub>

---

> Is the point of instantiation `f(i)`? It is a use of a template for a given set of arguments. If not what is it?

No, whilst `f(i)`, in this example, refers to the `f<int>` specialization *in a way that requires it to exist*, the point of instantiation of the specialization immediately follows the definition of `void h(int)`, *given that* the definition of `void h(int)` is the first definition that refers to the specialization, as per [[temp.point]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.point#1):

> **For a function template specialization**, a member function template
> specialization, or a specialization for a member function or static
> data member of a class template, if the specialization is implicitly
> instantiated because it is referenced from within another template
> specialization and the context from which it is referenced depends on
> a template parameter, the point of instantiation of the specialization
> is the point of instantiation of the enclosing specialization.
> **Otherwise, the point of instantiation for such a specialization immediately follows the namespace scope declaration or definition that
> refers to the specialization.**

---

> Stroustrup comments that the "point of declaration" for `f<int>` is after `h() {}`. Is the point of declaration different than point of instantiation?

Yes, the point of declaration is different from the point of instantiation. From [[temp.inst]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.inst#4) and [[temp.inst]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.inst#8):

> **[temp.inst]/4** Unless a function template specialization has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the function template specialization is **implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a function definition to exist**. [...]
>
> **[temp.inst]/8** If a **function template** or a member function template **specialization is used in a way that involves overload resolution**, **a declaration of the specialization is implicitly instantiated** ([temp.over]).

The former also depends on overload resolution, whereas the a function template can be instantiated without it being involved in overload resolution (e.g. explicit instantiations). As is covered by [[temp.point]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.point#8), a specialization for a function template may have multiple points of instantiations within a translation unit, but a declaration for the given specialization is naturally only generated once within a single translation unit (as is covered above: at first use in the context of overload resolution).

In your particular example, the invocation of `f(i)` in `h` will both implicitly instantiate `f<int>` as well as lead to the declaration of `f<int>`, as the invocation involves overload resolution, but these mechanisms are governed by different, albeit related, rules.

Comment: Stroustrup further states that "The point of instantiation for f<int>() is outside h(). This is essential to ensure that the g() called in f() is the global g(int) rather than the local g(double)."  So f(i) is not the point of instantiation.

Comment: @notaorb Yes, note that I just updated the answer a few minutes ago, prior to you posting this comment. `f(i)` is just the just refers to the specialization in a way that requires it to exist, but the actual point of instantiation is immediately after the definition of `void h(int)`.

Comment: So `f(i)` invokes implicit instantiation, which generates code from the template?  This code and it's given declaration for the template arguments is added after `h()`?  Thanks

Comment: Also if the declaration of `f(i)` is after `h()` how will the compiler find `f(i)`?  Thanks again

Comment: @notaorb The `f(i)` invocation does not _invoke the implicit instantiation_ (an instantiation is not invocable), it _leads_ to the implicit instantiation of the `f<int>` specialization, and the related _point_ of instantiation is immediately after the definition of `h()`. The _definition_ of the specialization is not "located" immediately after `h()`. The definition of the specialization is just the instantiation of the definition of the primary template, under the same restrictions as the name lookup restrictions as the _point of the primary template definition_, as is covered by my answer ..

Comment: ... to your previous question. Point of instantiation is something entirely different than _the definition of a function template specialization_. The definitions are _instantiated_ as covered (extract) in my answer above, but the the _point_ of the definitions cannot be argued about in the same way as the point of the instantiations. The point of the instantiation of a function template specialization requires the primary template or a explicit spec definition to exist, but it only controls _where_ that definition is instantiated, not how the definition is scoped (ref. to other question).

Comment: @notaorb But this chat is growing your question from **two** questions into **numerous** ones. **Please ask only one question per post**, and use separate posts for other/follow-up questions (see e.g. [the following meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)). Also, consider reading up on the standard sections I have cited above prior to asking another question ("research prior to question"). I will consider _this_ particular post answered (at least I will not spend any more time on it and my original answer of it).